# NanoFramework lacking libraries

Tags: c#, interop, nanoframework

I wanted to try something different than the standard c/c++ so I installed nanoFramework on my ESP32 and I really like it, but I found that there are many 3rd party libraries that are just not available for c#. There is c/c++ interop, but that essentially means I have to create a C# wrapper for every library I need. Is there a better way?

List of sensors I would like to use and could not find libraries for:

- Thermometer
- Scale
- Microphone (could be implemented pretty easily actually, just reading analog pin should suffice)
- Humidity sensor
- Oled display (I know not a sensor. I mean [this](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-ssd1306-oled-display-arduino-ide/))

Comment: Well, if there is no libraray (wrapper or c#-nativ) then why not be the person to provide such a library to the rest of the world?

Comment: @Ackdari Maybe once I actually know what I am doing, this was merely an IoT noob stumbling on a shiny new tool and looking for a way to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest that you take a look at the .NET IoT Core [repository](https://github.com/dotnet/iot).
There a bunch of binding there and we are in the process of making possible to use this from .NET nanoFramework.